# opencv::meanStdDev with vector<vector<double>>

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I want to calculate the mean and stdDev of a 2d vector using `cv::meanStdDev`. But it keeps getting error. Here is an example of my code

```
vector<vector<uchar>> v = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
Scalar mean, stddev;
meanStdDev(v, mean, stddev);
```

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= i && i < (int)vv.size()) in cv::_InputArray::getMat_, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 1244`

If I change it to 1d vector. It works

```
vector<uchar> v = {1,2,3};
Scalar mean, stddev;
meanStdDev(v, mean, stddev);
```

The document states that `cv::meanStdDev` can take `vector<vector<_T>>` as InputArray. What did I do wrong here? Much appreciated.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: I updated the error in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in your code/post indicates where that error actually occurs.  Try wrapping the call in a try catch block, that may provide more information when you look at the exception in the debugger.

Comment: It seems to be an issue in OpenCV's getMat_() routine.  According to OpenCV's doc [http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=inputarray#inputarray] a vector< vector < T>> should work, as you state.